# Overloading a method in Groovy using Closure arguments with different return types

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm reasonably proficient with Groovy insofar as my job requires, but not having a background in OOP means that some things still elude me, so apologies if some of the wording is a little off here (feel free to edit if you can make the question clearer).

I'm trying to create an overloaded method where the signature (ideally) differs only in the return type of the single Closure parameter. The Closure contains a method call that returns either an ItemResponse or ListResponse object, both of which could contain an object/objects of any type (which is the type I would like to infer).

The following code is a simplified version of what I'm trying to implement - an error handling method which takes a reference to a service call, safely attempts to resolve it, and returns the item/items from the response as appropriate:

```
public <T> T testMethod(Closure<ItemResponse<T>> testCall) {
    testCall.call().item as T
}

public <T> List<T> testMethod(Closure<ListResponse<T>> testCall) {
    testCall.call().items as T
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there any alternate approach/workaround that would achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create an overloaded method where the signature
>   (ideally) differs only in the return type of the single Closure
>   parameter.

You cannot do that because the return type is not part of the method signature.  For example, the following is not valid:

```
class Demo {
    int doit() {}
    String doit() {}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I only included the code snippet to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve. I was asking if there's any way of actually doing what that code would _ideally_ do

Comment: @Tom You said "I'm trying to create an overloaded method where the signature (ideally) differs only in the return type".  That can't be done.  That is what I was addressing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by yourself and @jeffscottbrown, you can't have two methods with the same parameters but different return value. The workaround I can see here is to use a call-back closure. The return value of your `testMethod` would default to `Object` and you would provide an "unwrapper" that would the bit after the closure call (extract `item` or `items`). Try this out in your GroovyConsole:

```
class ValueHolder <T> {
    T value
}

Closure<List<Integer>> c = {
    [1]
}

Closure<ValueHolder<String>> d = {
    new ValueHolder(value:'hello world')
}

Closure liu = {List l ->
    l.first()
}

Closure vhsu = {ValueHolder vh ->
    vh.value
}

// this is the generic method
public <T> Object testMethod(Closure<T> testCall, Closure<T> unwrapper) {
    unwrapper(testCall.call()) as T
}

println testMethod(c, liu)
println testMethod(d, vhsu)
```

It works with both a list or a value holder.